# xampp MySQL Admin control panel

Tags: xampp

Downloaded and install Xampp version 5.6.24. Apache Admin opens fine but when try to open MySQL Admin it shows error Object not found. The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942229/xampp-object-not-found-error

Answer (score 1):

You can enter phpmyadmin in your browser via localhost/phpmyadmin if that is what you mean?

Comment: Yes when I enter http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ it show Object not found error 404.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Web Server also should be started