# Controller not being called from view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to make a login page using codeigniter.
I have 3 files login_view.php, login.php, login_model.php

login_view.php is the view file

login.php is the controller file

login_model.php is the model file.

This is my view.

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

      <body>
   <div class="container" style="margin-top:25px">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2 col-md-push-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1 header">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/dtulogo.png"/> 
      </div><!-- /col -->
      <h1>University Registration System</h1>

    </div><!-- /row -->
  </div>



  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">

     <div class="form col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2 col-md-push-3 col-xs-11 ">

      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="">Member</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- <div class="tab-content"> -->

        <div id="student">   

          <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
          <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>login/member_login_handle" method="post">

            <div class="field-wrap">
              <input type="text" placeholder="MEMBER USERNAME" id="member_username" name="member_username" required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
              <input type="password" PLACEHOLDER="MEMBER PASSWORD" id="member_password" name="member_password" required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>" />

            <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>

          </form>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the controller file

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library(array('session'));
}



public function member_login_handle()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    echo "<script>alert('in the member function');</script>";
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('member_username', 'Memeber Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('member_password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){ 
        $this->index();
    }
    else{

        $result = _check_database();

        echo "<script>alert('$result');</script>";
    }
}


public function _check_database()
{
    echo "<script>alert('in the database function');</script>";
    $member_username = $this->input->post('member_username', TRUE);
    $password = $this->input->post('member_password', TRUE);

    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $result = $this->login_model->validate_member_login($member_username, $password);

    if($result){
        return true;
    }
    else{           
        return false;
    }
}


public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
}
```

The view page is not calling the controller page. I have added some debugging code as an alert box also in the controller page. But it is not executing. Please see to as what is the problem in this code.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What do you mean the view isn't calling the controller? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @kchason. Yes i meant that only. When i click on the submit button, the output is "Object Not Found" in xampp.

Comment: Can you access /login/member_login_handle without the form? This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942229/xampp-object-not-found-error

Comment: Yes i can access the controller function.

Comment: Also change $result in the model to "return $query->result();" You have to return the result so the controller gets the data

Answer (score 0):

For starters - you have this in your controller

```
$result = _check_database();
```

And as it is a method inside a class, you need to refer to it with $this->, as you have everywhere else...

So it becomes...

```
$result = $this->_check_database();
```

That will should get you a little further along.

**For your Debug** you might want to change this...
(Not sure if a js alert will display a boolean...)

```
else{

    $result = $this->_check_database();

    echo "<script>alert('$result');</script>";
}
```

So to translate the boolean to words, try something like this...

```
else{

    $result = $this->_check_database();
    $debug_result = $result ? 'TRUE':'FALSE'; // Translate Boolean to a string
    echo "<script>alert('$debug_result');</script>";
}
```