# xamp is showing htdocs file/folders but showing error on opening the files/folders

Tags: php, sql, html

My problem is that XAMP shows object not found error.

I have changed the port to 8080 and i have also removed index.html and index.php files but still its not working.

Apache and MySQL is showing green light and MySQL is working fine

The error message:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost
>
> Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/5.6.34

When I type the url http://localhost:8080/ it shows the all htdocs files but when i click any file it shows error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP Object not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942229/xampp-object-not-found-error)

Comment: no its not a duplicate of that i am writing a correct url and all folders in htdocs are showing but folders are not opening

Answer (score 0):

Check DocumentRoot setting in XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf to find currently it is pointing to which folder.

You just need to change the root of project from **xampp/apache/htdocs** to **xampp/htdocs**.

I mean your project folder has to be in **xampp/htdocs** root .(e.g: `xampp/htdocs/project`).

And your project address will be `localhost/project`

> NB:Ensure that the server is running at port 8080