# How to get XAMPP to display webpage?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, xampp

I was testing some application for registering user and sending a welcome notification to my Mailhog in PHP via XAMPP. I couldn't get it to function because it keeps showing error

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

However, when i run this same application (as in my VS Code workspace) via my Docker, it works perfectly fine. I quite do not understand why. I tried as much as possible to mirror my docker unto my system (Ubuntu 22.04) , but i can't get XAMPP to display my webpage.

I need explanation as to why this is happening.

N.B- My Docker work directory has NGINX running, but i want to run this app via XAMPP.

Comment: Does anything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942229/xampp-object-not-found-error) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP Object not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942229/xampp-object-not-found-error)